# mysql left join and group by not returning all results in left table

Tags: php, mysql, join, activerecord, group-concat

I have the following tables:

extra_questions:

[image]

and extra_examples:

[image]

and I want to join and concatenate them such that I return all questions, but within each question, I show a dropdown containing all the questions' tags from extra_examples.

I currently have this statement (using codeigniter/activerecord):

```
$this->db->select('extra_questions.*, GROUP_CONCAT(extra_examples.tag) as tag',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('extra_questions');
        $this->db->join('extra_examples','extra_questions.id = extra_examples.question','left outer');
        $this->db->group_by('extra_examples.question');
        $this->db->order_by('extra_questions.id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
```

which returns as $questions. But when I loop through the $questions:

```
 <?php foreach ($questions as $i=>$questions_item): ?>
            <?php print_r($questions_item['id']); print_r($questions_item['tag']); echo '<br/><br/>' ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I get some strange results:

```
2flower,insect

3
```

Where I would expect:

2flower insect
3
4

But 4 is missing entirely. I want to make sure all questions are returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing left outer join with left join. Not sure but you can give a try

Comment: Could you please try changing `$this->db->group_by('extra_examples.question');` to `$this->db->group_by('extra_questions.id');` because `extra_examples.question` is NULL for question 4.

Comment: I've tried every join type - doesn't work

Comment: @mapek - yes! Please mark this as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @mheavers I've added it as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
$this->db->group_by('extra_examples.question');
```

to

```
$this->db->group_by('extra_questions.id');
```

because `extra_examples.question` is NULL for question 4.

Answer (score 1):

Your group by should be on extra_questions.id insteadof extra_examples.quesion